# Stop very low quality answers from appearing at Google results

Tags: discussion, support, google

Today I was googling what does `http error 1009` means and I noticed that the first result is coming from *Stackoverflow* and is displaying a very low quality answer; that is also **wrong**.

[image]

> Jul 14, 2011 - It means Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object ...
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/6689464/1549700

Google is a searching engine and that's perfectly acceptable since is a valid result.

However, isn't there anything *Stackoverflow* can do to prevent this?

Comment: Fetches beer & chips and waits for a couple of 20k users to delete the answer ...

Comment: You can stop drinking and munching now.

Comment: That answer was *never* highly upvoted, so I'm stumped on why Google would display it to begin with. Maybe because it was the first answer posted? Doesn't make a lot of sense in light of all the other information available. Good catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm [with Bill here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319575/stop-very-low-quality-answers-from-appearing-at-google-results#comment325688_319575); a bit in awe at how or why Google decided to index *that* particular answer. Could it be that it was the only answer that had `#1009` in plain text? The problem is we have no idea. Could it be that the answer was linked somewhere on Reddit or something?

We also can't really tell search engines what to index, the majority of internal links are already nofollowed, it would be up to Google to take cues from the answer score, and I have no idea if they do that or even can.

The thing to do is just delete really bad negatively-scored answers *if* they're an embarrassment to the site, that's why we give 10k+ users the ability to do it. Given the breadth and depth of answers, there's bound to be more that squeaked by - but we do a pretty darn good job with the majority of them. Now that the answer link no longer works, it'll be dropped from their index quickly, and hopefully they pick something better :)

Comment: 10k+ users can vote delete only questions, they don't have the ability to delete answers. Users need 20K+ to be able to delete negative score answers

Comment: Considering how few delete votes 10k+ users get, and how many bad posts we have, expecting us to make more than a tiny dent in them is... Optimistic.

Comment: "I have no idea if they do that or even **can**" - Sure they could if they wanted to, I guess. Also it would be prudent to do so. If they do however....

Comment: Is there any statistics on how many negatively scored answers got deleted by the 20k+ users?